# "Term Expected" error in tailwindcss generated css

Tags: css, intellij-idea, tailwind-css

I am working on an **node.js express** project using **EJS** as template engine. I am developing this on Intellij Ultimate Edition. [Intellij's tailwind css plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15321-tailwind-css) is installed. I am using tailwindcss v3 as my css framework. I have followed their [Get Started](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) guide and I am using Tailwind CLI as my method of installation.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ['./views/*.ejs'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I am building the css like so:

`npx tailwindcss -i source.css -o public/stylesheets/style.css --watch`

**source.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

So all is working fine, no issues, however I am a no error/warning in IDE kinda fellow (*read OCD*), and the error/warning shown in the IDE is bothering me and I want to know how to fix it OR if it is meant to be this way, then how to suppress it?

I have added a screenshot for reference. Let me know if more info is needed to debug, I'll be happy to provide them.

[image]

Comment: Please check that Tailwind plugin is installed: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tailwind-css.html

Comment: I should have mentioned that tailwind-css IntelliJ plugin is already installed in my post. (I will add that now). I have also tried invalidating cache and restart as well.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov, upon checking the link that you posted above, looks like IntelliJ is recommending not to have “@tailwind base;” in the style.css. (source.css in my case). Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Answering my own question)*

So, looks like `@tailwind base;` is the culprit.

According to tailwind doc:

> Built on top of modern-normalize, Preflight is a set of base styles for Tailwind projects that are designed to smooth over cross-browser inconsistencies and make it easier for you to work within the constraints of your design system.

> Tailwind automatically injects these styles when you include @tailwind base in your CSS

Looks like this has some styles which Intellij thinks are wrong and hence shows errors/warnings. You can read more about it [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight).

Quick solution is to **remove @tailwind base;** from your **source/input.css**, and it seems safe to remove as long as you are fine having minor inconsistencies between browsers.

I will reconsider my decision of removing it as my app matures. <strike>Not sure if it is an IntelliJ issue or a Tailwind issue. Please advice and I can open up an issue accordingly.</strike>

**EDIT:**
I found a way to disable IntelliJ inspection to just one file. This solution is imo a better one than removing @tailwind base from your source.css

You can do this by opening the culprit file and going over to the inspection bubble (top right, with checkmarks, crosses etc) and then click on Highlight:None.[image: Disable inspection]

I have also started a discussion on the tailwindcss git repo [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8150).